# getaddrinfo throws a segmentation fault

Tags: c

So it took me a while to figure it out, since 'segmentation fault' doesn`t show any codeline, but apparantly this is causing a segmentation fault in my program:

```
if (getaddrinfo(options.servername, (char *)options.portno, &hints, &ai) < 0) {
    bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "Could not recieve server adress\b");
}
```

The variables are set as following

```
struct opts {
    long int portno;
    char *servername;
};

struct opts options;
parse_args(argc, argv, &options);

// Create Socket
struct addrinfo hints;
struct addrinfo *ai, *aip;

hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
```

I am pretty new to C, and especially the pointer stuff is still very strange to me, so hopefully somebody could find a possible cause.

Comment: Finding the error line: if you ran the program under a debugger, e.g. `gdb`, then you'll be able to trace out what line it stopped on after you've hit the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply casting an integer to `char *` doesn't convert it to a string. Rather, it causes the value of this integer to be interpreted as a memory address. In other words, you're trying to use your port number as a memory address.

You should convert it to a string first if you want `getaddrinfo()` to use it:

```
char port[16];
snprintf(port, sizeof(port), "%ld", options.portno);
if (getaddrinfo(options.servername, port, &hints, &ai) < 0) {
    bail_out(EXIT_FAILURE, "Could not recieve server adress\b");
}
```

Comment: or leave the parameter null and copy the int value into your sockaddr_in afterwards. Sockets aren't allowed to be >64K I don't think so I'm not sure long makes sense.

Comment: @Rup: Completely agreed.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to `memset` `hints` with 0's and try that. `memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));`

`hints` contains some pointer members that internally might be trying to get dereferenced.